# Who built the Jedi Temple on Coruscant?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi

Who built the Jedi Temple on Coruscant? Both Canon and Legends answers are acceptable.

Comment: There's an extensive history here; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Palace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### "The Four Masters."

[image]

According to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Four_Masters/Legends), a group of ancient Jedi known as the Four Masters constructed the Coruscant Jedi Temple in both continuities. Very little additional information is known about them.

Comment: And they sorted the Jedi into four houses ...

Comment: @WilliamJackson Earth, Wind, Water and Fire...